# Objective-C Property getter throwing exception 'Unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, unrecognized-selector

I'm new to Objective-C. I'm experiencing a problem trying to use a property getter. I have a property to access an instance of a very simple class. My interface looks like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
//...
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) MyController* myController;
@end
```

And my implementation looks something like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{
}

@synthesize myController = _myController;
....
//Getter
- (MyController*)myController
{
    return _myController;
}
@end
```

Elsewhere in my project I am trying to use the getter. It fails miserably.

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
MyController* myController = appDelegate.myController; //unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Being new to Objective-C, I'm sure I'm doing something horribly wrong. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the call that instantiates `appDelegate` with the following:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Right now you are sending a message to a `UIApplication` instance, rather than an instance of `AppDelegate`. Note that the return type of `+[UIApplication sharedApplication]` is `UIApplication *`, and the return type of `-[UIApplication delegate]` is `id<UIApplicationDelegate>` (at run time, assuming all is configured correctly, this delegate object will be an `AppDelegate` instance.

The error message would likely have given you a hint here - it would have probably been something like:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication myController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The presence of `UIApplication` in the reason section tells you that the `UIApplication` class doesn't recognize this selector, while the `-` before the square brackets indicates that the message was sent to an instance of `UIApplication`. If you had sent an unrecognized selector to a class object, then the `-` would be replaced with a `+` (this is a common notation for communicating method signatures).